# What's the difference between these two forms of SSH tunnel commands?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I've been using `ssh -L` in the following format for a long time to connect a locally running web frontend to a remote RPC or HTTP service.

```
ssh -L <local port>:localhost:<remote port> <remote host> # Format 1
```

Recently, I've found myself using a different type of tunnel for connecting to a SQL database which I could only access from another server within its private network, formatted as follows.

```
ssh -L <local port>:<final target host>:<remote port> <intermediate remote host> # Format 2
```

While I understand what functions these two forms serve, I don't have a good mental model for how both can work. When I only knew about the first one, I assumed that `ssh -L` meant "pass traffic on port `local port` to `remote port` on `remote host` and then redirect response traffic back to `localhost`." This would indicate that `remote host` is the recipient of forwarded traffic.

Format 2 and the `ssh` man page (in particular this passage [1]) lead me to believe otherwise. Both treat the host listed between the ":"s in the `-L` argument, not the `remote host` at the end of the command, as the final recipient of forwarded traffic. Furthermore, format 2 uses the host passed at the end of the SSH command as an intermediate junction for traffic, in addition to initializing a remote shell session.

To summarize, the second type of `ssh -L` command leads me to believe that the first type shouldn't work as it does. Why can format 1 work as a way to forward traffic on `local port` to `remote port` if format 2 treats `remote host` as an intermediate stop for traffic?

[1]

> -L [bind_address:]port:remote_socket  Whenever a connection is made to the local port or socket,   the connection is forwarded over the
>   secure channel, and a  connection is made to either *host* port
>   *hostport*, or the Unix  socket remote_socket, from the remote machine.

Notice how this passage never mentions the *hostname* parameter, passed as the final argument to any SSH command (for example, `ssh -L <local port>:<...>:<remote port> <hostname>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are very close to understanding, there are just a couple things to clarify.  So given the following SSH command issued on a client computer:

```
ssh -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport user@server
```

This command is going to initiate an SSH connection with `server` and establish that direct connection.  The `-L` directs the SSH client to open a port (the port number is `port`, bound to the client network interface specified by `bind_address`) on the client computer.  This allows another piece of software on the client (like a web browser or DB management tool) to connect to that port and any traffic sent will travel through the SSH tunnel and on the `server` computer the SSH server will open a connection to `host:hostport` and send the traffic via that connection to the `host` computer.

In your Format #1 example, your webserver and your SSH server are the same computer, and therefore `host` is just `localhost`, meaning the `localhost` of the SSH server.  In your second example, you are using the SSH server as an intermediary to access a different remote computer, but the key is that the SSH server is able to make the connection to that computer (`host`).  So, in reality both commands are doing the same thing, the only difference is one is making the final connection to a service on the same computer as the SSH server and the second is making a connection to a remote server.

Comment: Awesome thanks! This answers it for me. The key piece I was missing is that `host` is relative to `server` not the original starting point.